# Why can I change the sign of this expression?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation; $2\vec{k}\cdot\vec{G}=-G^2, \vec{G} = u_1\vec{b_2} + u_1\vec{b_2} + u_3\vec{b_3}$ where $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are integer.

I saw the statement that the equation $2\vec{k} \cdot \vec{G} = -G^2$ is equal to $2\vec{k} \cdot \vec{G} = G^2$ because $-\vec{G}$ is also $\vec{G}$.

But I can't understand why they are same expression.

I need more explanation.

Comment: Perhaps $\vec k$ is an arbitrary vector? We need more context.

Comment: This is from solid state physics. G is reciprocal lattice vector. k is incident beam wavevector. In fact, there is more conditions; $k=k', \vec{k'} - \vec{k} = \vec{G}$ but this context seems not essential so I excluded. Do this context deal with this problem?

Comment: Could you provide a link for the book or PDF where this is from?

Comment: From this link : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331984878_Kittel_Charles_-_Introduction_To_Solid_State_Physics_8Th_Ed

Download the pdf and check 31 page. 
Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the material:

> When the scattering vector ${\bf \Delta k}$ is equal to some particular reciprocal lattice vector ${\bf G}$, $${\bf \Delta k} = {\bf G} \tag{21}$$ [...]
> From (21) we found ${\bf \Delta k} = {\bf G}$ or ${\bf k} + {\bf G} = {\bf k'}$ so that the **diffraction condition** is written as $({\bf k} + {\bf G})^2 = k^2$ or $$2{\bf k}\cdot{\bf G} + G^2 = 0 \tag{22}$$ [...]
> When ${\bf G}$ is a reciprocal lattice vector, so is $-{\bf G}$ and with this substitution we write $$2{\bf k}\cdot{\bf G} = G^2 \tag{23}$$

We first assume that ${\bf \Delta k}$ is a reciprocal lattice vector and we denote it by ${\bf G}$, but then, since ${\bf -G}$ is a reciprocal lattice vector as well, we change the notation to ${\bf \Delta k} = -{\bf G}$. Therefore, replacing ${\bf G}$ with ${\bf -G}$ in $(22)$, we arrive at $(23)$.

You can think about it like this: we first denote ${\bf \Delta k} =: {\bf G}$ and derive $(22)$ and say ${\bf H} := -{\bf G}$, replace ${\bf G}$ in $(22)$ with ${\bf -H}$, then rename ${\bf H}$ to ${\bf G}$ so that in $(23)$, ${\bf G}$ is not ${\bf \Delta k}$ anymore, but $-{\bf \Delta k}$.